# What type of jellyfish is this?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

Friends of mine recently came back from a visit in kenya and on the kenyan beach they said they found several jellyfish with "sails" on their head. We tried finding out what they were and found one image online that was exactly the type of jellyfish they found:

[image: Sail jellyfish]

What kind of jellyfish is it?

The guide told them that they're dangerous and those are just the corpses without stings or something, but nobody knew it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the jellyfish your friends saw actually look like this *and* if they were small (Wikipedia says they're usually less than 7 cm in length), they're likely [Vellela vellela](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velella) or sometimes called By-the-wind Sailors for the way the raised part catches the wind and is blown along the ocean's surface.

Wikipedia writes

> ...all possess nematocysts, in some species the nematocysts and toxins
>   therein are more powerful than other species. V. velella's nematocysts
>   are relatively benign to humans, although each person may respond
>   differently to contact with the nematocyst toxin. It is wise to avoid
>   touching one's face or eyes after handling V. velella, and itching may
>   develop on parts of the skin that have been exposed to V. velella
>   nematocysts.

Some photos.
[image]
[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYGmbKFU7T4)

[image]
[Source](http://www.utaot.com/2013/09/11/velella-wind-sailor-of-the-seas/)